# Mysql Update multiple records

Tags: c#, mysql

I have many customers who create many tickets and that these tickets are waiting for a result, the functions are similar to a bingo, where there are many tickets created (around 20000) waiting for the final result, once you know the result, I have a program that verifies, ticket for ticket, and asks if the ticket is equal to the result, then the ticket is marked as winner or loser, the issue is that when there were few records everything worked fine, but now it takes too long update those 20000 tickets, the worst is that I have many events in a row, then at a time for example I should update 50000 ~ 10000 records, and this may take several hours. Is there any way to update this in blocks?

the structure of tickets is like this

```
CREATE TABLE `Ticket` (
  `ClientID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `TicketID` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BetAmmount` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `Gain` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(15) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=Simple ;2=Combinado',
  `Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Choice`varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `EventID`int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TicketID`),
  KEY `idx_ClientID` (`ClientID`),
  KEY `idx_status` (`Status`),
  KEY `idx_EventID` (`EventID`),
  KEY `idx_Date` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14455815 ;
```

Result Table

```
CREATE TABLE `Event` (
      `EventID` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `Result` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

      PRIMARY KEY (`EventID`),     
      KEY `idx_Date` (`Date`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then my program ( developed with c#) run, and ask ticket per ticket if result is correct

first i load all ticket with same eventID, and i store it in datagridview, next i make a pause for 0.1 second, and next i load the result for this event, and i run row per row, and i update the record

in C# program

```
//MYSQL Connection
DbTicketsRecords=mysql.select('select * from Ticket where idEvent="xxxx"');
dgvTickets.DataSource = DbTicketsRecords;

DbResult=mysql.select('select * from Event where idEvent="xxxx"');

Thread.sleep(100);

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvTickets.Rows)
  {
    string Choice = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    string TicketID=row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    if(Choice== DbResult.fields('Result'){
         DbTicketsRecords=mysql.select("update Ticket set status='win' where TicketID='" + TicketID+"'");
     }else{
         DbTicketsRecords=mysql.select("update Ticket set status='Loss' where TicketID='" +TicketID+"'");
     }
  }
```

note: the program performs some additional operations, but in synthesis those are the main functions.

Then my question is, I could do this operation with better efficiency, what I could do to improve the process?

Comment: For starters, you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: How will this take several hours? There is something wrong with your system. There most likely isn't any reason to run more than one statement though since you can update all states at once. Or not even update them but have a separate table for winning IDs

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen , really it can take 10~20 minutes per event, but at certain times, I have to update 10 events, then we talking 100~200 minutes

Comment: @ZoharPeled Could you show me some example?

Comment: @marjes no. I have almost no experience with MySql. Most of the time I'm working with SQL Server. However, you can quite easily [do a search.](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=c%23+mysql+parameterized+query&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=c%23+mysql+parameterize&aqs=chrome.3.0j69i58j69i57j0.12239j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Just run an update that updates all rows at once. You have the eventId, you have the choice that should be winning. Update all rows to choice=correct one. Done.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. PS There is no reason to do any looping for a given (say) bingo ball. You seem to need to read an intro to relational databases & querying them.